# Is there an English equivalent for the Swedish expression "the droplet that caused the beaker to overflow"?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, popular-refrains

In Swedish, the expression "det var droppen som fick bägaren att rinna över", directly translated to "the droplet that caused the beaker to overflow", is used to express that enough is enough. Is there a similar expression in English?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_that_broke_the_camel%27s_back "This is a reference to any process by which cataclysmic failure (a broken back) is achieved by a seemingly inconsequential addition, a single straw." See also: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/last+straw http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-last-straw.html http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/the-last-straw?q=last+straw However, it is **not an exact match**.

Comment: Actually, it was the last+1 drop. :)

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

> The straw that broke the camel’s back.

[This write-up](http://voices.yahoo.com/the-straw-broke-camels-back-origin-of-3103808.html) traces the saying’s history back to long ago, noting that [Seneca once wrote in “On Despising Death” (Letter XXIV)](http://thriceholy.net/Texts/Letter24.html):

> Counting even yesterday, all past time is lost time; the very day which we are now spending is shared between ourselves and death.  **It is not the last drop that empties the water-clock**, but all that which previously has flowed out; similarly, the final hour when we cease to exist does not of itself bring death; it merely of itself completes the death-process.

And the online thesaurus seems to think that [“match in the powder barrel”](http://thesaurus.com/browse/straw+that+broke+the+camels+back) is a synonym for “the straw that broke the camel’s back”.

Comment: I never realised it was a drinking straw.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be. A dried stalk of grain does the job too. The point is.. it's very light :)

Comment: You might also say: "it was the final straw".

Comment: There's a slight problem though. The drops were **not** a problem until and except for the last one. The drops were useful. The last straw is by contrast, merely another of the small burdens, i.e., part of the problem. Cf. Wikipedia entry en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_that_broke_the_camel%27s_back  
 "This is a reference to any process by which cataclysmic failure (a broken back) is achieved by a seemingly inconsequential addition, a single straw."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, what makes you think it's a drinking straw?  I always thought it was a stalk of hay.

Comment: I do believe that Edwin Ashworth was making a joke...

Comment: Being Swedish myself, this is the expression I tend to prefer to translate that idiom. It isn't a literal *translation*, but then again idioms rarely translate well literally anyway.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: That's part of what makes them _idioms_ :^)

Comment: Typo: "match in the powDer barrel".  @thcrist can you find 5 other characters to tweak?

Comment: @J.R. That was kind of my point :)

Comment: @Kristina, I always imagined wheat/barley/oats.  I'm not sure what I'd call a stalk of hay (probably a stalk, now I'm typing it!), but not a "straw".  That's in northern England, if it matters.

Comment: @TobySpeight as I've only just learned, straw is made from the stalks of grain plants (which belong to the grass family), but hay is made from the blades of grasses (not the stalks). So... A blade of hay? Probably a strand is more natural.

Answer (score 3):

I just have to include my favorite expression, ***"It's always the last thing you did that got you in trouble"*** - it somehow always seems to be true.  In your expression, it was adding that last drop that overflowed the beaker.

Comment: How about some feedback, downvoter?

Comment: There are so few hits in a Google search that I also have to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfectly elegant way to say it and it is known in the English lexicon. It does, however, suggests too much of something **good**, rather than bad:

> > > His cup runneth over.

It's a Biblical excerpt
.
Used in the negative sense, it might make for a clever play on words, say, used for irony or a sarcastic comment. Context would matter. Example:

> > After her speeches on altruism and the disgrace of poverty, the head cheerleader's cup runneth over with catty comments about her family and her lifestyle.

Answer (score -2):

Either:

> This is the drop that filled the glass.

or else simply:

> This was the last drop!

There are probably more (as @tchrist's answer shows).

Comment: "This was the last drop" means something completely different, it's usually said when you no longer can control your anger!

Comment: @vsz Really? Well, that explains the downvotes. I know it's usually said when you can no longer control your anger but not exclusively. Thanks for the feedback.